# Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Is it possible to trigger a journey when i only have the record id in the data extension and that record id is also present in the CRM and i need to fetch the email address from CRM and trigger a journey. Can we achieve this scenario?

Please let me know how to proceed with this kind of request.

Comment: I have not configured synchronized data sources to marketing cloud but maybe my answer still can help.

Inside journey builder - Settings you can chose which "default email address" should be taken. In this case you would have to use the "use email attribute from contacts". And when your contactmodel is attached to the synchronized datasource i believe that this email value has to be available inside this step, because the contact model always stores subscriberkey and emailaddress together. (and i would assume that you can take the crm value there, but i don't know it).

Comment: I have tried this in contact builder, i have setup a relation between my data extension record id with the account object id and in the journey builder setting i have used "use email attribute from contacts" option from still its not triggering an email @JohannesSchapdick

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the Data Extension as the Entry Source then you will need the Email Address in the data extension.

You can either query from the synchronized data extension into your journey data extension or use Salesforce Data as your entry source.

> If the data for the journey is stored in multiple data extensions,
>   create a single entry source data extension using a query. Create
>   queries in Automation Studio using the SQL Query Activity.

More information on Entry Sources: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_entry_source_best_practices.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null